# Is there a way to access OSX System Dictionary programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, dictionary

Using Objective-C and the Cocoa API, how can I search the OSX System Dictionary definition of "dog" and retrieve the results so I can display them?

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? The link is about accessing via AppleScript which has nothing to do with accessing it via Cocoa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [DictionaryServices framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html) to get definitions from the active system dictionaries as text (`CFString`), or to show a dictionary window with the definition.

Comment: This a great blog post about [Dictionary Services on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/dictionary-services/). The post also includes this handy Objective-C wrapper around the dictionary services called [DictionaryKit](https://github.com/mattt/DictionaryKit).